# Create multiple S3 buckets at once

Tags: terraform

I am trying to create a static website using S3 buckets.  I want to create a bucket for www and non-www versions.  I can't work out how to create two buckets at once.  I read that you can chain two entries together using square brackets.  And I read that you can use variables in the json file.

So far I haven't managed to get variables or multiple entries to work.  Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong?

I have used this code:

**Main.tf**

```
provider "aws" {
  shared_credentials_file = "C:/Users/Eoin.Oliver/.aws/terraform.tfvars"  
  profile                 = "customprofile"  
  access_key = "${var.access_key}"
  secret_key = "${var.secret_key}"
  region     = "${var.region}"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "b" {
  count      = "${length(var.domain_name)}"
  bucket     = "${var.domain_name[count.index]}"
  acl        = "public-read"
  policy     = "${file("bucket-policy.json")}"

  website {
    index_document = "index.html"
    error_document = "error.html"

    routing_rules = <<EOF
EOF
  }
}
```

**Variables.tf**

```
variable "access_key" {}
variable "secret_key" {}
variable "region" {
    default = "eu-west-2"
}
variable "domain_name" {}
```

**terraform.tvars**

```
domain_name             = ["website.com", "www.website.com"]
region                  = "eu-west-2"
access_key              = "xxxxxxxxx"
secret_key              = "xxxxxxxxxxx"
```

**bucket-policy.json**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
     "Statement": [
        {
             "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": ["arn:aws:iam::240479180938:user/${iams_user_name}"]
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutBucketPolicy",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::${domain_name}"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make changes in `Main.tf` as specified below:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "b" {
  count      = "${length(var.domain_name)}"
  bucket     = "${element(var.domain_name, count.index)}"
  acl        = "public-read"
  policy     = "${file("bucket-policy.json")}"

  website {
    index_document = "index.html"
    error_document = "error.html"

    routing_rules = <<EOF
EOF
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, very helpful.  Do you also know how to make the variables in the JSON part work?

Comment: I tried this and I got this error: Call to function "element" failed: cannot read elements from string.

Comment: I tried this but no avail `${tolist(var.domain_name)[count.index]}"`

Comment: what is your terraform version?

Comment: it is 0.12.7 I just downloaded it very recently.